# Conditional Expectation Question regarding excess premium over claims

Tags: probability, statistics

> Two life insurance policies, each with a death benefit of \$10,000 and a one-time premium of \$500, are sold to a couple, one for each person. The policies will expire at the end of the tenth year. The probability that only the wife will survive at least ten years is 0.025, the probability that only the husband will survive at least ten years is 0.01, and the
>   probability that both of them will survive at least ten years is 0.96. What is the expected excess of premiums over claims, given that the husband survives at least ten years?

I want to understand what excess of premiums over claims means. Is it the profit we are talking about here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With excess of premiums, they mean the total expected cost for the couple. This can be calculated as follows:

1. The man pays \$500 and survives the 10-year period. The total cost is thus $500.
2. The woman pays \$500 as well, but we are not sure she will survive. Applying Bayes' theorem, we know that the following holds for the events $M$ (the man lives after 10 years) and $W$ (the wife lives after 10 years):
   $$P[W|M] = \frac{P[W,M]}{P[M]} = \frac{0.96}{0.96+0.01} \approx 0.9897$$
   The total expected cost for the woman is thus $\$500 - (1-0.9897) \cdot \$10000 \approx 396.91$.

Overall, we get a total excess of premiums of $\$500 +\$396.91 = \$896.91$.

Comment: Thank you! You explained in a much simpler way. Could you still explain me something that I am still confused about? Maybe I am not understanding the question properly. Is the question asking  the cost to the couple or to the insurance company? I thought the insurance company only pays out to the person that dies. Since husband survives, the policy expires and company gets the profit from the husband, right? But, they have to pay out for the wife who died before policy expired.

Comment: Why is 10000*(1-.09897) being deducted from 500? Is it because 500 is paid by the couple to receive the benefit of 10000?

Comment: They have to pay two times \$500, but if the woman dies (with probability 1.03%) they get \$10000 from the insurance company.